# Word for mildly popular (used as a compliment)

Tags: word-choice, american-english

I'm trying to find a word for something meaning *not explosively popular or successful, yet not a failure*. It should not be intended as criticism and should represent something not necessarily *new* but more forthcoming or predicted to be destined for eventual greatness.

> Alphie's _______ novel *Xyz* is a ....

Comment: It's not entirely applicable (and I can't find a citable definition, so no answer) but consider the phrase [sleeper hit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeper_hit). (Unfortunately you'd probably only use this after the fact, when you know it's a hit, as opposed to immediately at release.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Middling* comes to mind, but there is a slight negative connotation to it, even if the meaning is very close to "average".

Comment: It's good enough for me. For most it's probably vague enough that the negative connotation doesn't take root.

Comment: @DaemonOfTheWest- I disagree- if something is described as "middling" it is taken to be mediocre- which is definitely something no one wants to be.  I'd go with Coty's *respectable* or perhaps *ahead of its time*

Comment: @Jim Certainly a valid point, but "mediocre" (to my ears at least) carries an even stronger negative connotation than "middling" (which really just means *average* as in "middle-of-the-road"). By right, "middling" should be a neutral expression, but it's acquired a negative connotation because nobody wants to be "just average" (even though statistically, half of the population would be exactly this or worse). "Respectable" carries less pejorative baggage than either "middling" or "mediocre", so it may be a better choice, but a lot of people would still regard it as "damning with faint praise".

Comment: @Deepak "statistically, half of the population would be [average] or worse." This is a common fallacy but it's completely untrue. For example, vastly less than half the population has a below-average number of legs.

Comment: @DavidRicherby ....and yet vastly more than half the population has an average number of legs, rounded to the nearest leg.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I never expected to need mathematical rigour in an English SE site, but I'm certainly up for it. Fine, I'll amend my assertion to "In the case of a continuous variable distributed normally, exactly half the population would be expected to be below the average". Happy? In any case, this is an extreme level of nit-picking, because the non-technical English language in general lacks this level of precision. The word "middling" certainly isn't that precise. In the case of the discrete distribution of the number of legs, it makes more sense to speak of the median or the modal number.

Comment: @DavidRicherby (cont'd) In which case, a normal biped would indeed be considered "middling" (but not mediocre) as far as their lower appendages were concerned, because they would have exactly the median or modal number of legs. And unless a freak of nature had 3 legs, there would be no more talk of having a greater than average/median/modal number of legs at all.

Comment: @Deepak Yes, I'm happy with the revised version. But it's *not* extreme nitpicking. The "half the people must be below average" fallacy comes up all the time, and it comes up precisely because it's only true for symmetric distributions. In reality, there are many, many things whose distribution is not symmetric about the mean. Wealth is a good example.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I reiterate that it *is* extreme nitpicking on an English site. The word "average" does not necessarily refer to the mean (arithmetic or any other form). It can be used to refer to the median or the mode. As evidence, you may consult this M-W definition: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/average (def. 1) And when dealing with a skewed distribution (like wealth), the median would be a more natural choice as a measure of central tendency than the arithmetic mean. In which case, my assertion that half would be at or below the average (median) would be spot-on.

Answer (score 27):

"Well-received"

> Alphie's novel *Xyz* was well-received.

It doesn't claim undue respect, and emphasizes that the novel was not a failure.

"Respectable" is another option.

There is a saying, 'damned with faint praise,' that comes into play here, but I believe that these two options show due appreciation to the actual accomplishments of the work without insulting or embellishing.

Comment: I don't think this works. A "well-received" novel is one that the critics like; it may or may not be particularly popular.  Likewise, "respectable" more addresses the quality of the novel than it's popularity.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I don't think well-received *necessarily* means well-received by critics, though that's probably the most common usage.

Comment: "Creditable" is one I often hear in a sports context. "Xyz put in a creditable performance"

Answer (score 5):

trending, aspiring, up-and-coming, promising, worthy, (respectable)

Comment: "Aspiring" doesn't work: it means wanting to improve itself. "Worthy" sounds like damning with faint praise, to me.

Comment: i think promising is pretty good. it's the first thing that came to mind for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't demand a single word, you could use something along the lines of "fairly popular", "reasonably popular", "decently popular", "somewhat popular" or "respectably popular". Moving farther from the fill-in-the-blank format, you could describing it as having had "good/decent/respectable sales".

Answer (score 0):

"Enjoyable" seems like it would fit. Not too positive but not negative either.

Answer (score 0):

"Popular" by itself seems to convey what you want. If you wanted to single it out for extra praise you'd usually add to that.

I'd rate Tom's "promising" as about as good as any.

"Well liked" may serve.

"Better than average" or "better than many" or even "better than most" all convey a sense of noticeable or notable but are clearly not what you'd use in a 'rave review' so may suit your need.

Maybe "aspiring", "trending"(yuk), "up & coming", writer or story 'to watch'.

---

FWIW I'd rate "middling" in the "damned with faint praise" category. I'd be disappointed to have that rating applied to anything of mine (whether deserved or not :- ).

Answer (score 0):

**"likable"** seems to fit.

"likable" (adj) - easy to like, having pleasant or appealing qualities. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/likable)

"He isn't exactly popular but those who know him say he is a likable kind of guy."